# Is 'data corruption occurs in the clustered index' still open?

Tags: azure-sql-database, clustered-index

Based on [sp_Blitz Result: DBCC CHECKDB Not Run Recently](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/dbcc-checkdb-not-run-recently/), there is a reported bug in `SQL Server 2012 & 2014`, [Data corruption occurs in the clustered index when you run online index rebuild in SQL Serve](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2969896/fix-data-corruption-occurs-in-clustered-index-when-you-run-online-inde), is it still an open issue in `Azure SQL Server 2019`?
How can I investigate it?

Comment: The bug you linked to was fixed in SQL 2012/2014, so it is not an issue on newer versions. Are you saying that you read sp_Blitz and it returned the "DBCC CHECKDB Not Recently Run" message? Have you run checkdb?

Comment: He mentioned to do CHECKDB nightly instead of rebuilding index nightly. As far as I understand one of his reasons to check database nightly is because of losing data because of rebuilding index.